# attempting to navigate a user to login if cookie is undefined

Tags: angularjs, cookies

In my app.run domain of angularjs, I am attempting to check if cookie is defined and if not defined redirect the user to the login page. If the cookie is defined, the page loads well to the page but if the cookie is undefined, the page does not load well as it keeps refreshing or reloading on the login page at an endless loop.

here is the snippets

```
app.run(["$rootScope","$location", "$cookies", function($rootScope, $location, $cookies) {

var token = $cookies.getObject('token');
        if (token !== undefined) {
            $rootScope.user = token;
            $location.path(originalPath);
        }else{
            alert("5900");
            $(location).attr('href', '/login');//when cookie token is not defined, this window keeps loading endlessly
        }
```

while is login url, reloading endlessly when token is undefined

Comment: can't you check if you are already on `"/login"` page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add an early escape if you're already on the login page:

```
app.run(["$rootScope","$location", "$cookies", function($rootScope, $location, $cookies) {

if (window.location.href.match(/\/login/)) {
    return;
}

var token = $cookies.getObject('token');

if (token !== undefined) {
    $rootScope.user = token;
    // Commented this line out, because if there's a token, the user doesn't need to be redirected anywhere
    // $location.path(originalPath);
} else {
    alert("5900");
    $(location).attr('href', '/login');//when cookie token is not defined, this window keeps loading endlessly
}
```

P.S. Why don't you use `$location.path('login')` to redirect to login page?
`$location.path` is both a setter and a getter, as stated in the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location#path).

**EDIT**: Commented out line `$location.path(originalPath);` with explanation

Comment: The main focus in my solution is the addition of the early `if ($location.path().match(/\/login/)) {return;}`, the other one was just an observation

Comment: Wait ... so what's the problem? 

1. Your app is stuck in an infinite loop of redirects because of this line `$(location).attr('href', '/login');`?

2. This line `$(location).attr('href', '/login');` isn't working so nothing's happening?

Comment: What is the URL of your login page? And also, can you please explain again what this logic is meant to do? Because I believe it might be a slightly wrong approach.

Comment: Do a console.log with all the possible ways of getting the URL in order to figure out which one would work

Comment: Update the if statement to use window.location.href and see if it runs `if (window.location.href.match(/\/login/)) { alert("44"); return; }`

Comment: That's probably because of this line `$location.path(originalPath);`

Comment: why did u comment this out... // $location.path(originalPath); what about doing something like this window.location.href; in that location

Answer (score 0):

Try to check if already is on login page, something like this condition bellow,

```
var currentUrl =  window.location.href;
if(currentUrl.indexOf('login') != -1){
    //Already login
}
else{
    //Not login
}
```

Comment: this keeps executing the else block

Comment: Yes, if there is no word "login" in the current URL in browser, so that means that is open some other page, but if there is "login" in URL, in that case it will go to if condition

Comment: the app is taking a turn between if/else block

Comment: var currentUrl =  window.location.href;
  if(currentUrl.indexOf('login') != -1){
      //Already login
   alert("4");
   $(location).attr('href', '/index');
  }
  else{
      //Not login
   alert("3");
   $(location).attr('href', '/login');
  }